# Autoplay video on device boot

Tags: video, boot, automation

I have a Noontec A9 Android Smart Box TV thingy that needs to play a video on loop for a very long time.

I found multiple apps that can do this but I am looking for one that will start playing the video as soon as the app starts.

The device is going to be placed in a duty-free area. The problem is that between 12 and 6 AM the power is switched off so the player will turn off and on in the morning. Using [Automateit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage&hl=en) I can start an app at boot but I just cannot find one that will auto play the video.

Any idea on what I should do? Maybe another solution? The device is rooted.

Comment: Hi, I' don't have a solution for your problem but I' would love to get a screenshot of AutomateIt running on Smart TV :-)

Comment: @Muzikant I will make one screenshot. But this is not the SmartTV, is the Noontec A9 Android Smart Box TV

Comment: posted my question here http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36794/play-loop-video-on-startup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make that video player default for video files. Then, use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) to `Open File` on boot. `Open File` action can be found in `File` action category. `Device Boot` context can be found in `Event` ~> `System` category.